# Gender of an adjective form with "tout" as subject?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord

> Mais cette année tout est différent.
>   But this year everything is different.

Why not use "différente"? Année is feminine. And "tout" according to the dictionary is either masculine or feminine noun. For "être", the gender must match, no?

Comment: « Mais cette année, somme toute, est différente. »

Answer (score 1):

"différent" agrees with the subject. Here, "année" is not the subject.
You may say (subject being bold) :

> Mais **tout** est différent
>   Mais **cette année** est différente
>   Mais cette année, **tout** est différent

Adding a comma makes it clearer I guess, but here, the subject is "tout". 
I don't know where did you find that "tout" can be feminine, but as a indefinite nominal pronoun, it's not, it's neutral, so used as a masculine. The feminine of "tout" is "toute", and cannot be used this way.

You may see usages [here](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-ne-pas-confondre-tout-adjectif-indefini-pronom-indefini-adverbe-variable-dans-certains-cas-et-substa-99597059.html) (first example in brackets because doesn't seem to fit) :

> **2b- TOUT pronom indéfini nominal**
>   Il représente un ensemble de personnes ou de choses.
>   (La patience n'est pas donnée à tous.)
>   Tout, dans vos gestes, me rappelle votre mère.
>   C'est tout.
>   Tout est là.
>   Ce sera tout ou rien.
>   Proverbes. Tout passe, tout lasse, tout casse.
>   Tout est bien qui finit bien.
>   Etc.

Comment: *Tout* is **not** a noun here, it is an indefinite pronoun. And it is not masculine, it is neutral (as such follows agreement rules of masculine). *Tout* is a noun only if preceded by *le* ("the whole").

Comment: @Laure Indeed, "TOUT pronom indéfini nominal", didn't find it, I'll edit answer :)

Comment: You should remove the first example which does not belong in your series: *La patience n'est pas donnée à toutes.* is correct. In general, where *tous* can be used, *toutes* can be used too.

Comment: @GAMPUB Thanks, I added brackets, since it's a quote